# MediaDefiningClass Object is not iterable ?

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

Trying to use Inlines to get customised view at Admin Dashboard. Below is the code

```
from django.contrib import admin # noqa
from oscar.core.loading import get_model
from oscar.apps.catalogue.admin import *

CategoryAttribute = get_model('catalogue', 'CategoryAttribute')
CategoryAttributeValue = get_model('catalogue', 'CategoryAttributeValue')
Category = get_model('catalogue', 'Category')

class CategoryAttributeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CategoryAttributeValue
    fk_name = 'category'
    extra = 1

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CategoryAttributeInline,]

admin.site.register(CategoryAttributeValue)
admin.site.register(CategoryAttribute)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

The error I am getting is 
`TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable`

What is the problem in my code ?

Comment: At what line is the error occurring?  Please post the traceback.

Comment: Are you using some custom ORM field, like JSONField, BTW?

Answer (score 4):

sometimes the cause of this error was sending arguments to the register function in the wrong order.

Check the order of registering a ModelAdmin: it’s the model class first, then the ModelAdmin class.

Example: admin.site.register(Model, ModelAdmin)

I suppose naturally the second one has to be the ModelAdmin since register(MyModel) works as well.